# How to make Ajax update table in wordpress database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I tried some steps I saw on the internet on how to send forms without refreshing the page using ajax but I cant seem to do it fine. Here is my code inside the form

```
$(".coupon_thumbsup").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("click");
        var ThumbsUp = $(this).parent().find(".ThumbsUpVal").val(); 
        ThumbsUp = parseInt(ThumbsUp) + 1;
        $(this).parent().find(".ThumbsUpVal").val(ThumbsUp);
        $(this).find(".green_thumb").css('background', 'url(http://www.accessdoorreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/smalllike2.jpg)');
        var totalvotess = $(this).parent().parent().find(".numofvotes").text();
        totalvotess = parseInt(totalvotess) + 1;
        $(this).parent().find(".ThumbsUpVote").val("1");
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".numofvotes").text(totalvotess);
        var successpercentv = ((ThumbsUp/totalvotess)*100).toFixed(2);
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".successpercent").text(successpercentv);
        console.log(successpercentv);
        var ThumbsDown = $(this).parent().find(".ThumbsDownVal").val(); 
        ThumbsDown = parseInt(ThumbsDown);
        var companycouponid = $(this).parent().find(".companycouponid").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insertcouponthumbs.php",
            data: {'ThumbsUp': ThumbsUp, 'companycouponid':companycouponid, 'ThumbsDown':ThumbsDown},
        });
    });
```

And this is my php file:

```
<?php add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' ); 
function my_action() {
global $wpdb;
$comcoupid = $_POST['companycouponid'];
$resultcoupon = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_coupon_list WHERE ID = $comcoupid");
foreach ($resultcoupon as $keyy) {
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix."coupon_list", array(
        'ThumbsDown' => $_POST['ThumbsDown'],
        'ThumbsUp' => $_POST['ThumbsUp'],
        ), array('ID'=>$keyy->ID)
    );
}
wp_die();
} ?>
```

Comment: in your `wp-config.php` file, change `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and in your browser developer tools, check console for errors.

Comment: It just says `Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/accessdoorreview/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1633`

Comment: what PHP and WordPress version you are using, if both are latest, then this issue is likely to be due to either your theme or plugin

Comment: please in your question also add the code, where you enqueue this js file of yours